# Does Python Template Engines use the exec statement?

Tags: python, template-engine

I can only find that "Chameleon compiles markup templates into python byte code" [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating). How other template engines works? Using the exec statement to execute Python code inside the HTML (or any other markup language) file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, i don't think so.. I think they would parse the code and convert it to python bytecode themselves.

Comment: Thanks. How do you think they do that? With the compile function maybe?

Comment: Because using `exec` would be too dangerous, and will cause problems with the template themselves. Converting them to bytecode looks like the best solution.

Comment: Ok, that's a great answer. But how do you think they do it?